# ref to a label with a new link name

Tags: cross-referencing, ref, nameref

I would like to reference to a section. The section named as "My Section" and has the lable "sec:my-section"

In default use cases I use \ref or \nameref to reference to the section. With \nameref Latex print out the section name like "My Section". But now I need a command like the HTML a Tag to reference to the section "My Section" but as an other name, as example "First Topic".

Here are my example

```
\section{My Section}
\lable{sec:my-section}
Lorem impsum... \nameref{sec:my-section}{First Topic}
```

In HTML

```
<a href="www.google.de">Google</a>
```

Has Latex a package or a function to rename a link?

Volker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `\hyperref[sec:my-section]{First Topic}`

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{My Section}
\label{sec:my-section}

Lorem impsum... \hyperref[sec:my-section]{First Topic}

\end{document}
```